# Chrome extension: storage.set() does not accept variable as keyword

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use `chrome.storage.local` in my extension. This is a test that I coded up:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'test': 'foo'}, function() {
  chrome.storage.local.get('test', function(data) {
    console.log("Test Result: ")
    console.log(data);
  })
});

var keyword = 'test2';
chrome.storage.local.set({keyword: 'foo'}, function() {
  chrome.storage.local.get(keyword, function(data) {
    console.log("Test 2 Result: ")
    console.log(data);
  })
});
```

The only difference between the first and the second test is that I replaced the string `test` by a variable holding the string `test2`. Now, you'd expect these both to work, right? The output is:

```
Test Result: 
Object {test: "foo"}
Test 2 Result: 
Object {}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh yes, it in fact is! Can someone mark this a duplicate? Sorry for the noise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant set the key of a json object to a variable, make an object first then set the key and value

```
var obj = {};
obj[keyword] = 'foo'
chrome.storage.local.set(obj, function() {
```